# React JS + React Router works with $.get but not $.ajax PUT

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, reactjs, react-router

I've got a react.js setup and I've got some simple routes using react-router. I have a dispatcher:

```
import dispatcher from "../dispatcher";

export function reloadList(){
    dispatcher.dispatch({type: "FETCH_LIST"});
    let serverRequest = $.get("../../data/list.json", 
        function(data){
            console.log(data); //Logs correct data from list.json
        }
    );
}

export function saveList(list){
    dispatcher.dispatch({type: "SAVE_LIST"});
    let serverRequest = 
       $.ajax(
         url: "../../data/list.json",
         dataType: 'json',
         method: 'PUT',
         data: list,
         success: function(data) {
             console.log("success!");   //does not output
         },
         error: function(xhr, status, err) {
           console.log(status, err.toString());  //outputs a 404 error
         }
       });
  )
}
```

The `reloadList()` function runs fine and outputs the JSON data. The `saveList()` function throws a 404 error. I'm assuming this is because of the way the app handles routes, but I'm confused as to why it works with get and not put (or post for that matter).

I've been struggling with saving data to a file in react, this seemed like the right way at first but now I'm not so sure. Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume based on your phrasing, that you're using some sort of simple HTTP server (or no server at all) for developing locally, and `list.json` is a file on your machine. If this is the case, your issue is that your HTTP server doesn't have the routing to know how to handle `PUT`s (or `POST`s, or probably any method other than `GET` for that matter). If you want to write files to your system you will need to add an actual backend that can handle a `PUT` and more intelligently interact with the filesystem.

Unfortunately there's no simple way to write files to disk in the browser alone (for security reasons), but if you want to avoid adding to your backend, you could look into creating files for download [using a Blob](http://jsfiddle.net/uselesscode/qm5ag/)

Comment: Yes you are correct, I am developing locally, just running a simple node.js server. I didn't realize that I needed a server to handle post requests. I had planned on adding one anyways so it's really no big deal, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the contents of a file on the server from the browser using only an ajax request. Think about how terribly insecure the internet would be if I could change files on **your** server just by sending an ajax request.

You're going to need some server side code that can handle such a request. For instance, you can setups a simple Node / Express server that has a route which can handle reading and writing to disk, using the built in `fs` module.

Maybe later on you'll want to use a database instead.

http://expressjs.com/en/starter/installing.html

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to Node, I'm still getting used to the whole framework, I'll look into using express.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure your server routes the PUT request, not just GET. 
For example express.js routes like this:

```
   `app.get("/getRequestHere",function(){});
    app.put("/putRequestHere",function(){});`
```

Some browsers (Chrome) restrict the ability to make PUT/DELETE requests. It sents out an OPTION request that returns 404. What you want to do is put this in your .htaccess file:

```
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
    Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token, accessToken"
    # Added a rewrite to respond with a 200 SUCCESS on every OPTIONS request.
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
```

first parts accepts access for PUT methods,
second part forwards (rewrite) OPTION method requests into an 200 response. This code I copied somewhere else on stackoverflow and it totally works.

(stop down voting me guys. This answer totally works)

Comment: You're being downvoted because the OP didn't mention anything about having a server...